# Комбинаторная задача на перестановки

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация, комбинаторика, динамическое-программирование

Есть 3 числа: A, B и C. Необходимо получить выражение A+B=C, при этом чтоб C было минимальным. Нужно переставлять биты внутри чисел (переставлять можно только в пределах одного числа. Т.е можно поменять какие-то 2 бита внутри числа А, но нельзя поменять два бита из А и B).

Ограничения на числа `2^31-1.`

Решения может не существовать, все числа положительные.

Ну перебором тут не выйдет. Пробовал генетический алгоритм, в некоторых случаях он работает, но, к сожалению, не во всех. Возможно задача решается способами динамического программирования или программированием по профилю, но не особо понимаю, как должна выглядеть динамика.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Это обычный (арифметический) `+`? А числа со знаком или unsigned?

Comment: @avp, числа без знака, ну а насчет плюса, то других не знаю :) Видимо, обычный

Comment: Тогда элементарно. Переместить в каждом числе все единички вправо (так получим минимальное число из заданного количества единичек).

Comment: Но ведь числа могут быть разной длины. Например, если есть число 111, 10010 и 101000, то 111 + 011 = 011 не будет верным. Ну или я что-то не так понял

Comment: Не ясно условие. Если A = 1, B = 1 и C=0, то каким образом вы предлагаете переставить биты, чтобы получить равенство A+B=C?

Comment: Исправил условие

Comment: А точно не перебор с next_permutation? Ну если нет, то, наверное, динамика...

Comment: Да, я не правильно понял (невнимательно прочел) условие задачи. Ну, суть (двигать всюду биты вправо) осталась. Дальше какая-то итеративная подборка. В принципе с вашим набором битиков в примере (111, 10010, 101000) получим `7 (111) + 3(11) = 10 (1010)`

Comment: Ну это будет работать не всегда. Ведь не всегда из С можно получить сумму А и В (со сдвинутыми битами). Например, A=111, B=110, С=111001000. Если сдвинуть А и В, то выйдет 7(111), 3(11). В сумме 10, но из С 10 никак не получить. Тем не менее решение существует 13(1101) + 10(1010) = 23(10111)

Comment: Я же сказал об подборке. Если минимальное `C` больше суммы минимальных `A` и `B`, то постепенно увеличиваете их, если `C` меньше, то увеличиваете (вставляя 0 в разные позиции, конечно, начиная со старших) `C`. И т.д. В конечном итоге это что-то напоминающее двоичный поиск (или поиск экстемума функции, делением пополам)

Comment: Ну это же перебор по сути. Да, он может кончится раньше, но я думаю, что возможны такие входные данные, при которых данный подход будет работать долго. Но я попробую этот вариант

Comment: Перебор всех комбинаций 32 бит (все возможные значения unsigned int) занимает несколько секунд. Естественно, тупой перебор 96 бит займет годы, но направленный поиск, надеюсь, завершится быстрее

Comment: Если идти по пути перебора, то перебирать надо лишь комбинации с фиксированным количеством единичных битов.  Для этого есть остроумные приемы, которые именно так и перебирают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишу только алгоритм, автору думаю будет интересно самому реализовать.

1 - Перебираем число С (если делать правильно, то будет не больше 30 млн вариантов, С[31,15] ). В порядке возрастания.

Теперь проверим можно ли получить фиксированное С.

Для этого используем динамику.

Начальное значение `F[0][ bit_count(A)] [bit_count(B)][0] = true`;

Поля: {бит в С, осталось битов в А, осталось битов в Б, есть перенос бита}.

Значение - можно ли такое получить.

Пересчёт. Если в С бит `{i}` совпадает с переносом, то переходы либо два нуля или 2 едиинцы `{(a-1, b-1), (a,b)}` флаг переноса выставить в первом случае. Аналогично если не совпадают `{ (a-1,b), (a,b-1) }` флаг переноса не меняется.

Если `F[32][0][0][0] = true` то мы нашли что хотели. Восстановить ответ можно и не сложно (в крайнем случае ещё раз эту же динамику запустить).

Сложность порядка оценить тяжело, оценка сверху 30кк*32*32 но она очень грубая. В целом должно успеть (делать отсечение по отрицательному количеству не забывать).